Adding a stored procedure to an existing DataSource?
I have created a data source in Power Apps and added multiple stored procedures to it. Now I need to add more stored procedures and was wondering how to do that.

You added multiple stored procedures to it already?  How did you pull that off?

The SPROCS are already created in the DB.  We are using the add datasource in Power Apps and selecting the SPROCs we need.  Then we realized we missed a few and wanted to know if there was a way to add the missing ones without deleting the old datasource and creating a new one.

Oh okay, the way the question is worded sounds like you want to know how to make more SP's, but you already have them, and you want to know how to add more of them to your powerapps project?  What database are you using?

If they aren't showing up you can try to Refresh your connection, and if not click the Add New Connection and do a Refresh there and see if they show up able to be selected?
